# External command-line child process in C doesn't give output until it ends

Tags: c, input, command-line, process, output

I'm having strange issues spawning a process, i found almost nothing related to this...

I need to spawn a command-line child process and be capable of getting its output and sending input before it ends.

I can do it fine with cmd.exe, and runs smooth...
BUT when i try to do it with external command-line applications they doesn't output nothing to my program until end of execution. I can send input, it processes normally, the number of times i want to, and at finish of child i get ALL the accumulated output.

The related code is:

```
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secatr;
secatr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
secatr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
secatr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

CreatePipe(&stdin_read, &stdin_write, &secatr, 0);
CreatePipe(&stdout_read, &stdout_write, &secatr, 0);
SetHandleInformation(stdout_read, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);
SetHandleInformation(stdin_write, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);

STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

memset(&pi, 0, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
memset(&si, 0, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
si.hStdError = si.hStdOutput = stdout_write;
si.hStdInput = stdin_read;

CreateProcess(NULL,c:\\\\app.exe, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, "c:\\\\", &si, &pi);
handleproceso = pi.hProcess;
handlethread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL,0,&Read,NULL,0,NULL);
_beginthreadex(NULL,0,&Write,NULL,0,NULL);

WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
CloseHandle( pi.hThread );



unsigned __stdcall Read(void *a){
char buff[100];

while(1){
    memset(buff,0,sizeof(buff));
    ReadFile( stdout_read, buff, sizeof(buff)-1, &dwRead, NULL);
    send(socketcliente,buff,strlen(buff),0);
    if(exit1){
        exit1 = false;
        break;
    }
}
return 0;
}



unsigned __stdcall Write(void *a){
char ddd[100];

while(1){
    memset(ddd,0,sizeof(ddd));
    if(recv(socketcliente,ddd,sizeof(ddd)-1,0) == SOCKET_ERROR){
        CloseHandle(handlethread);
        TerminateProcess(handleproceso,1);
        break;
    }
    WriteFile(stdin_write, ddd, strlen(ddd), &dwWritten, NULL);
    if(strncmp(ddd,"exit",4) == 0){
        exit1 = true;
        //CloseHandle(handlethread);
        break;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

I tried the MSDN example of [How to spawn console processes with redirected standard handles](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/190351) , with the child process fflushing output buffer it receives the output fine...if I remove that fflush i get the same problem of other programs.

The portion of code looks as:

```
printf("Child echoing [%s]\n",szInput);
     fflush(NULL);  // Must flush output buffers or else redirection
                    // will be problematic.
```

What can I do if the program I want to spawn doesn't behave that way?Can I force its output or something?

I cannot find any response to that in the whole internet...Thank you in advance and apologies for my basic english.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

or at the beginning of your program just disable buffering:

```
setbuf(stdout, NULL);
```

Comment: I can't modify the child program, only parent.